# Http status code to status messages in C++

Tags: c++, http, c++11, libcurl, http-status-codes

I have written a simple program using LibCurl that does some http stuff. I was wondering if there is any library with function that can convert http status codes to status messages or LibCurl has any function to do that?

Input => 200

Output => OK

I am using C++11

Thanks

Comment: Servers respond with their own optional texts in status messages. Use a header function for getting the first line with a status text

Answer (score 0):

**This library would help you.**
https://github.com/j-ulrich/http-status-codes-cpp

You can get the appropriate HTTP status code as string using,

`std::string HttpStatus::reasonPhrase( int code );`